# org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact - when using mvn 3.0.4 (works with mvn 3.0.3!)

Tags: maven-3, artifactnotfoundexception

With some multi-module maven project we'r having the following exception when using maven 3.0.4:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:resources (default) on project genericapi: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:resources failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 in gwt-plugin-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:resources (default) on project genericapi: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:resources failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 in gwt-plugin-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google:resources failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 in gwt-plugin-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:82)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:1.3.2.google or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 in gwt-plugin-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:353)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:321)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:78)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 in gwt-plugin-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:207)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 in gwt-plugin-repo (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/2.1.0.M3/gwt/maven)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:947)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :genericapi
```

Note: I compared the logs of mvn3.0.3/mvn3.0.4, they look equal, the only different is the exception that only occurs with 3.0.4,

More to say, I checked out maven trunk and changed Aether from ver 1.13.1 to 1.12 and everything works just fine! that means it's probably a bug introduced in Aether 1.13 and above.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Have you cleaned your local repository and tested with both versions?

Comment: Yes I did, as I mentioned, with 3.0.3 it works just fine.

Comment: Two things: Why are you using an old version of gwt-maven-plugin (Maven central has 2.4.0 see http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22gwt-maven-plugin%22) and why are you using a different repository in your case in particular with gwt-maven-plugin, cause it's available via central.

Comment: Yes the plugin is a bit old (before it was available publicly), I already tried to switch to 2.3.0/2.4.0 without the particular repo, the result is still the same (even worse as it causes some other aritfacts (except dom4j) to be missing).

Comment: Ok, to be more specific, this problem only occurs with Aether 1.13, with Aether 1.12 it works fine, I'll indicate that in the question's body.

Comment: Why did you checkout maven trunk ? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I was suspecting this is a bug in Aether 1.13, so I wanted to build maven with Aether 1.12 which works just fine. so I am pretty sure it's a bug somewhere between 1.12 - 1.13. what to do next?